# Повернуть текст в браузере на iOs

Tags: css, ios

На компе, на Androin свойство `transform: rotate(90deg)` работает корректно и поворачивает всю строку на 90 градусов

Но на iOS (проверял на разных iPhone) любые браузеры воспринимают это свойство некорректно, а именно поворачивают буквы на 90 градусов и сам текст, даже когда я указываю `-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)`

[image: Правильно]
[image: Некорректно на iOS]